# "Failed to connect to POP server pop.gmail.com"

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail, pop3

I use Thunderbird 60.8.0 on Win10. For years I've accessed my Gmail emails via a POP server. Forwarding/POP etc in my Gmail settings, and the Thunderbird account was set up correctly. Suddenly, since yesterday, I get "Failed to connect to POP server pop.gmail.com". I haven't changed anything in my settings recently. I tried changing to "Secure password": no success. What's going on?
[image: Thunderbird]
[image: Server settings]

Comment: Try changing the server name to `*.gmail.com` and maybe try setting the `Authentication method` to OAuth2 if it's an option.

Comment: Google have changed the authentication method. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441897/how-can-i-use-my-google-account-with-apple-apps-mail-calendar-etc-in-os-x-10

Comment: or just use IMAP- far easier.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ah, OK, thanks.